# Exporting CSV from ListView in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, csv, export

i am having a bit of issue with exporting my data from a List-view in VB.NET i have included screenshots of what i am seeing basically i want to see only the Values in my csv file when i export it,

as you can see i am seeing what the List-box is showing,  those values are coming from the List View Before Export. also i need the export to be in 1 column not rows as shown

any help would be great..

[image: Exported CSV]

[image: CSV-GUI]

```
'''' 
  Imports System.IO
  Imports System.IO.StreamReader
  Imports System.IO.StreamWriter
  Imports System.Data.DataSet

  Public Class Form1

Private Sub startcol_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles startcol.Click
    Timer1.Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Sub stopcol_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles stopcol.Click
    Timer1.Enabled = False

End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Const MIN As Double = 5.0
    Const MAX As Double = 400.0
    Const DEC_PLACES As Integer = 2

    Dim rnd As New Random
    Dim list As Integer()

    'Generate a random number X where MIN <= X < MAX and then round to DEC_PLACES decimal places.
    Dim dbl As Double = Math.Round(rnd.NextDouble() * (MAX - MIN) + MIN, DEC_PLACES)
    weight.Text = dbl


    Dim newItem As New ListViewItem(weight.Text)
    newItem.SubItems.Add(weight.Text)

    'newItem.SubItems.Add(TextBox3.Text)
    ListBox1.Items.Add(newItem)
    ListView1.Items.Add(newItem)
    rowcnt.Text = ListView1.Items.Count

End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Timer1.Enabled = True

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    ' ExportDatasetToCsv(List)
    'WriteToTextFile()
    Me.DoSave()

End Sub


Private Sub DoSave()
    Dim SFD As New SaveFileDialog()
    Try
        With SFD
            .AddExtension = True
            .CheckPathExists = True
            .CreatePrompt = False
            .OverwritePrompt = True
            .ValidateNames = True
            .ShowHelp = True
            .DefaultExt = "txt"
            .Filter = _
            "CSV Files (*.csv)|*.csv|" & _
            "All files|*.*"
            .FilterIndex = 1

            If .ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
                Me.DoSaveItems(.FileName)
            End If

        End With
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, Me.Text)
    End Try
End Sub

' save All values from ListView1
Private Sub DoSaveItems(ByVal fileName As String)
    If fileName Is Nothing = False Then
        If fileName.Length > 0 Then
            Using writer As New System.IO.StreamWriter(fileName)
                For Each currentItem As Object In Me.ListView1.Items
                    writer.Write(currentItem.ToString() & ",")
                Next
            End Using
        End If
    End If

End Sub

Public Function ExportListViewToCSV(ByVal filename As String, ByVal lv As ListView) As Boolean

    Try

        ' Open output file
        Dim os As New StreamWriter(filename)

        ' Write Headers

        For i As Integer = 0 To lv.Columns.Count - 1
            ' replace quotes with double quotes if necessary
            os.Write("""" & lv.Columns(i).Text.Replace("""", """""") & """,")
        Next

        os.WriteLine()

        ' Write records
        For i As Integer = 0 To lv.Items.Count - 1
            For j As Integer = 0 To lv.Columns.Count - 1
                os.Write("""" & lv.Items(i).SubItems(j).Text.Replace("""", """""") + """,")
            Next

            os.WriteLine()

        Next

        os.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        ' catch any errors
        Return False
    End Try

    Return True

End Function

Public Sub TestExportToCSV()

    Dim dlg As New SaveFileDialog
    dlg.Filter = "CSV files (*.CSV)|*.csv"
    dlg.FilterIndex = 1
    dlg.RestoreDirectory = True

    If dlg.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then

        If ExportListViewToCSV(dlg.FileName, ListView1) Then

            Process.Start(dlg.FileName)

        End If

    End If

End Sub


   Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles             Button3.Click
    'TestExportToCSV()


    End Sub
 End Class
''''
```

Comment: Show use the code to generate the csv records.  Looks a lot like your exporting ListViewItems rather than ListViewItem.Values

Comment: If it's not working then you're doing it wrong. If you don't show us what you're doing then we can't tell you what's wrong with it. We should NEVER have to tell you to SHOW US THE CODE. You need to post ALL the relevant information and the code that isn't working is ALWAYS relevant.

Comment: @Hursey Right pew, wrong church. :-) ListViewItem doesn't have a Value property. It does have a Text property which should solve the OP's problem.

Comment: This is a pretty common requirement and has been done many times.  Here is a tutorial with code: https://dotnetref.blogspot.com/2008/03/exporting-listview-to-csv-file-in-vbnet.html (one of many available online)  Hope it helps.

Comment: I have added my Complete Sourcecode

Comment: In DoSaveItems method, you’re calling writer.write(currentItem.ToString() & “,”). Change .ToString() to .Text

Answer (score 0):

As you haven't shown us your code, we can't tell you how to modify it specifically. In general though, you can treat the ListView somewhat like a 2D array, looping through the rows and the columns to get the data. That means that you could output the data to a CSV like this:

```vb
Using writer As New StreamWriter(filePath)
    For rowIndex = 0 To myListView.Items.Count - 1
        Dim item = myListView.Items(rowIndex)

        'Write a line break before all but the first line.
        If rowIndex > 0 Then
            writer.WriteLine()
        End If

        For columnIndex = 0 To myListView.Columns.Count - 1
            Dim subItem = item.SubItems(columnIndex)

            'Write a field delimiter before all but the first field.
            If columnIndex > 0 Then
                write.Write(",")
            End If

            writer.Write(subItem.Text)
        Next
    Next
End Using
```

That's the old-school way. There are more succinct options, especially with the advent of LINQ:

```vb
File.WriteAllLines(filePath,
                   myListView.Items.
                              Cast(Of ListViewItem)().
                              Select(Function(item) String.Join(",",
                                                                item.SubItems.
                                                                     Cast(Of ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem)().
                                                                     Select(Function(subItem) subItem.Text))))
```

EDIT:

If you want to include the column headers then you can modify the above code like so:

```vb
Using writer As New StreamWriter(filePath)
    For columnIndex = 0 To myListView.Columns.Count - 1
        Dim column = myListView.Columns(columnIndex)

        'Write a field delimiter before all but the first field.
        If columnIndex > 0 Then
            writer.Write(",")
        End If

        writer.Write(column.Text)
    Next

    For rowIndex = 0 To myListView.Items.Count - 1
        Dim item = myListView.Items(rowIndex)

        'Write a line break before each line.
        writer.WriteLine()

        For columnIndex = 0 To myListView.Columns.Count - 1
            Dim subItem = item.SubItems(columnIndex)

            'Write a field delimiter before all but the first field.
            If columnIndex > 0 Then
                writer.Write(",")
            End If

            writer.Write(subItem.Text)
        Next
    Next
End Using
```

```vb
File.WriteAllLines(filePath,
                   myListView.Items.
                              Cast(Of ListViewItem)().
                              Select(Function(item) String.Join(",",
                                                                item.SubItems.
                                                                     Cast(Of ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem)().
                                                                     Select(Function(subItem) subItem.Text))).
                              Prepend(String.Join(",",
                                                  myListView.Columns.
                                                             Cast(Of ColumnHeader)().
                                                             Select(Function(header) header.Text))))
```

Comment: Thank you @jmcilhinney, how can you select the column header text as your solution only selects the data without the headers

Comment: @MichaelMarmah, I have updated the answer to include column headers.

Comment: Please I get `Prepend` is not a member of `IEnumerable(Of String)` error

Comment: @MichaelMarmah, `Prepend` is an extension method, declared in the `System.Linq.Enumerable` class, so you need to have imported the `System.Linq` namespace in the file or in the project. Most new projects will do that automatically but you can do it manually if you need to. The method was introduced in .NET Framework 4.7.1, so you'll need to be targeting that or .NET Core. If you are targeting an earlier version, you can still use the same code to generate the header text but you'll have to use a different way put it all together, e.g. call `ToList` on the main data and then call `Insert`.

Comment: Thank you, will do just that, but finally what if the values already have `comma(,)`, how do you escape them since the CSV already uses `commas` to separate the values